# String builder underline text

Tags: c#, vb.net

How can I underline text in a string builder ?

```
strBody.Append("be a minimum of 8 characters")
```

I can't use HTML  tags

```
be a minimum of <u>8 characters</u>
```

Comment: What is the host ? Windows forms ? This depends on the control that holds that text and not the data itself.

Comment: No, you need to do that on the screen with a Sharpie.

Comment: This question demonstrates a fundamental misunderstanding of what a string is.

Comment: My understanding, is that underlined text is represented by the existence of invisible control characters.  It depends on whatever you're using to actually render the text.

Comment: I don't think you understand how strings work. Please read up on the programming concepts and try to make console applications before doing any GUI. It'll help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you guys for your advice. I am definitely in the process of learning no doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringBuilder` cannot underline text itself. You would want to underline the text when you attempt to display it, either in a WinForm or your webpage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)!

Answer (score 2):

You can't, a StringBuilder store a string ; not a formatted string.
It's up to the "recipient" of the content to underline it (some control setting or some boilerplate code in console or anything required depending on the environment)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, NO you can't do this using `StringBuilder`. Rather, to whichever control you are assigning this text have that control underline the text using it's styling property. (depends on whether it's targeted for `ASP.NET` or `Winform`)